# Getting the index of clicked select element

Tags: javascript

I have a page with different `select`s (they have no class, no id).

They are in different `div`s and different sections of the page (they are not under the same parent).

(These are events on a calendar, each one has different options using `select`s).

I need to know how to get the index (or number) of the clicked `select` each time someone clicks on one.

so far I have:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

var me = nodes.indexOf( $(this) );
```

but it always returns 1..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Comment: @JasonCust OP wants to get the index of the focused `<select>` element, doesn't seem like that's a duplicate. OP, In jQuery, you can use `$( "select" ).index( this );` to return the index of the current `select`, relative to the other `select` elements on the page.

Comment: do you need the index of the `select` element in the page or just the index of the selected `option` ?

Comment: Use `this` not `$(this)`, since `nodes` is a `NodeList`, and `this` is a `Node` (well, `Element`, which descends from `Node`). `$(this)` is a jQuery object; I'm surprised it returns 1 and not -1.

Comment: I need to know the index of the clicked/changed <select>, not of the selected option in a <select>

Comment: There is no "indexOf" method on HTMLCollection object (the result of getElementsByTagName). This should throw an error. Your question is missing some context. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: @TylerRoper: thanks, the `$( "select" ).index( this );` seems to work and gets the current index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### With jQuery

You can use jQuery's [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to return you the currently clicked select index:

```js
$("select").click(function() {
  var index = $("select").index(this);
  console.log(index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>One</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option>Two</option>
</select>
```

The reason you must specify the `$("select")` portion of  `$("select").index(this)` is because we want the index *within the context of all `<select>` elements* on the page.

---

### Without jQuery

You can combine [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and `indexOf`

```js
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches("select")) return;

  var index = [...nodes].indexOf(e.target);
  console.log(index);
}, false);
```

```html
<select><option>One</option></select>
<select><option>Two</option></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <select>
        <option value="1">First</option>
        <option value="2">Second</option>
        <option value="3">Third</option>
    </select>
    <select>
        <option value="a">A</option>
        <option value="b">B</option>
        <option value="c">C</option>
    </select>

<script type="text/javascript">    
        var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
        var selectList = Array.prototype.slice.call(selects); //convert nodes to array
        console.log(selectList);
        selectList.forEach(function (el) {
            el.addEventListener('change',function () { //add event on value change
                console.log(el.value);
            })
        })
</script>
```

this will work for all selects in the document.